# mdDialog.hide() by specifying class name of md-dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Only one material dialog can be open at a time however i am facing a case where i want to check that the dialog is of a particular class name before i hide it.
This is what i need - ( could not find anything online )

```
    $mdDialog.hide({

        className             : 'card-dialog'
    });
```

I am solving the issue currently by doing the following -

```
      if ( angular.element('md-dialog').hasClass('card-dialog') )
        $mdDialog.hide();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a feature request, which should be requested in the offical GitHub repository.

See http://github.com/angular/material

As said above, it's currently not possible.

Our `$$mdInterimElement` factory inside of the ngMaterial core, is not supporting any option to the `close` method yet.